# Make YouTube embedded iframe video fit perfectly in div without black bars?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, youtube

If I have the following markup:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <iframe src="link/to/video" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

and styling:

```
.video-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

How do I get the `video` to display full `width` and `height` in the `div`, without having it have those black bars on the top and/or sides, regardless of aspect ratio?

Comment: Looks like it's surprisingly hard to get the aspect ratio of the video by javascript without being the owner of the video.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
.video-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:56.25%; /* aspect ration for 16:9 */
    /*padding-top: 20px;*/ /* you can add padding-top if needed */
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.video-wrapper iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

This will keep responsive your video for all screens.

Comment: This is the perfect solution for all the screen orientations.

Answer (score 0):

Add class to frame tag

```
 <div class="video-wrapper">
   <iframe class="vid" src="link/to/video" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

then in CSS upscale it using transform property and hide the overflow on video-wrapper class

```
.video-wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
}

.vid{
 transform: scale(2.5);
}
```